# how to make heat sink under heat pads in kicad 7

Tags: pcb, thermal, heatsink, pad

Retired user here that have not designed a circuit in the last 3 years.
So I got myself KiCad 7 and boy oh boy things have changed!
Mostly for the better, but some things I used to do are now a real pain!

I am designing a PSU with some TO-220 tab regulator.
I am trying to use some free space on the PCB as a heatsink.
The idea should be easy, define a 'zone' underneath the tab.
But try as I might, the zone always end up covered with solder mask.

This would also be very useful for some chips that have thermal pads underneath.
I used to do this quite easily in older version of KiCad (I think I was using V5)

Thank you, Luc

Answer (score 3):

Just place a filled area on the solder mask layer.  That layer will be a negative, so anything you place on it will be "no mask".

Comment: Hello Peter :)Thanks for this!  It did not do what I wanted at first, but I've found a workaround! :)

Answer (score 1):

It did not work at first,the vias were isolated from the fill then I found a way around and it works perfectly now.
Here is how I do it, the instructions must be followed in the sequence I am about to describe.
Let's say I want a copper pad, under a TO-220 tab, isolated from the board planes but with vias to conduct the heat on both sides of the PCB.
First draw the outline on the top solder mask
Then place a fill the same size as the outline.
When the copper zone properties open, make sure both top and bottom layer are selected. Use fully hatched pattern, solid fill and assign the net to the same net as the tab of the device you are using. You can actually assign ANY net, but I found that it can become a bit confusing. Also make sure the pad connections are set to 'none' not to 'thermal relief.
Now place the fill.
Then place as many vias you want, the size and drill hole size as you like.
Now thanks to Peter above, the trick is to place a fill, the same size as the copper fill but on the top and bottom solder mask.
This will leave the board with bare copper the size and shape of the fill under the device.
Just do the operation in the order I have described. If you place the vias first, even if they are the assigned the same net as the fill, they will end up isolated from the fill.
It works! :)

Luc